# Vue.js - cannot read property even though the object exists

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, modal-dialog, vuejs2

I used *vue-resource* to fetch data from *firebase*. basically when I loop through each object under the *orders* directory, I match the *userId* of that object, find the object under the *users* directory, and save it on my local array as a nested object *(userData)* along with the retrieved *orders* objects. here's my code:

```js
//retrieve objects from orders
this.$http.get('https://nots-76611.firebaseio.com/Orders.json').then(function(data){
        return data.json();
    }).then(function(data){
        var ordersArray = [];
        for (let key in data){
            data[key].id = key;
            data[key].measurementsArray = Object.entries(data[key].measurements).sort();
            //retrieve a specific user based on the userId of each orders object
            this.$http.get('https://nots-76611.firebaseio.com/Users/' + data[key].userId + '.json').then(function(userdata){
              return userdata.json();
            }).then(function(userdata){
              data[key].userData = userdata; //store the object
            });
            ordersArray.push(data[key]); //pass the object along the userData
        }
        this.orders = ordersArray;
        console.log(this.orders);
    });
```

the object structured shown in the console is perfectly fine:

[image]

but when I try to, access the nested object in the dom via `{{ order.userData.Address }}`:

```js
<tr v-for="order in orders"
<dialog class="mdl-dialog" ref="userDialog">
                  <h4 class="mdl-dialog__title">Customer's Information</h4>
                  <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
                    {{ order.userData.Address }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
                    <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored mdl-js-ripple-effect" v-on:click="closeUser(ndx)">
                      OK
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </dialog>
</tr>
```

it says `Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Address' of undefined"`. I don't understand it because I can easily retrieve the properties in the *measurements* object (which is also a nested object)

did I messed up in the retrieval process? or in the DOM rendering?

EDIT:
I tried using `{{ order }}` instead of `{{ order.userData.Address }}` and it seems like the `userData` object was not stored in each of the `orders` object

Also, I noticed something strange about how the `userData` object is shown differently from the `measurements` object which is originally stored there along with the parent object:

[image]

Comment: just try `{{ order }}` instead of `{{ order.userData.Address }}` and see what its displaying.

Comment: @Pradeepb I can't comment the whole thing. But basically, the `userData` object was not stored properly :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two primary issues here.

First, the data is retrieved *asynchronously* which means, **it does not exist when the component is first rendered**. In the template you use

```
order.userData.Address
```

There is a point in time when there are `orders` but there is no `userData`, because the data has not been retrieved yet. That being the case, Vue attempts to render the orders, and tries to render `order.userData.Address`, but there is no `userData`. That's why you get the error, "Cannot read property 'Address' of undefined". In order to fix that, you should use a guard to make sure to only try to render `Address` when it is available.

```
{{orders.userData && orders.userData.Address}}
```

That will prevent the error.

There is a secondary error that you probably have not yet noticed. `userData` is not reactive. The reason for this is because [Vue cannot detect](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) when properties are added to an object *after* that object has been added to data. The code is setting `userData` like so:

```
data[key].userData = userdata;
```

and this occurs after the `orders` array has been added to the Vue because it is performed in an asynchronous call. Instead, you should use,

```
this.$set(data[key], 'userData', userdata)
```

Comment: thank you, the `this.$set(data[key], 'userData', userdata)` saved my day. Just wanna ask for the sake of curiosity though, the _guard code snippet_ that you've given... is it the same with the ones you put inside a `v-if`? I never thought that a conditional expression can be rendered in such a way. is it like saying to vue that "render those data if both order.userData and order.userData.Address are true"? what do you call that concept? I wanna research about it and its possibilities.

Comment: @Kaddy03 Yes, its pretty much the same as using a `v-if`. The guard is simply a javascript [boolean expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators). If the first part of the expression is falsy, the first expression will be returned, otherwise it returns the second expression. When `orders.userData` is undefined, it will return `undefined` and it won't evaluate the second expression. That prevents the error, and nothing is rendered because there is nothing to render.

Comment: thank you for that {{ data && data.property }} It's useful and save me hours but I still don't understand how it work. Isn't && indicate the conditional that return true or false? But instead it return the data.property.

Comment: @GTHell I can understand your confusion. There are two concepts in play. First is that in javascript an && expression evaluates to the right hand side of the expression if the first value is true. Second, boolean expressions **short circuit** which means, if the first part of the expression isn't true, the second part doesn't even get evaluated (because the expression is obviously false). This allows writing a short hand `if` statement which is useful in things like templates. You can try it right in the console. Try typing 1 && 2 in the console, and 2 will be the result.

Comment: @Bert I see! and 0 && 1 return 0 haha. I see why people making fun of javascript.

Comment: @Bert Your post saved my day. I spent over 2 hours in order to figure out this issue.
Your description about guard in javascript is very helpful. Thank you very much.
How much years of experiences do someone need to gain in Vue to grow as an expert in Vue&JavaScript?